# Contradictory output from ps -all after starting a docker container multiple times?

Tags: docker

I'm having trouble understanding the output of `docker ps -all` after starting the same docker container multiple times (because there is a problem with my understanding of docker).

To illustrate the issue:

1. I create a docker container by issuing:
   `docker create busybox date` which returns something like `b48a2a768679dd5cdb767d24f6632d6c3d37f735596bf2b5e47517b495d641af`
2. Next I do the following:

```
$ docker start -a b48a2a768679dd5cdb767d24f6632d6c3d37f735596bf2b5e47517b495d641af
Sat Jan 22 03:14:24 UTC 2022

$ docker start -a b48a2a768679dd5cdb767d24f6632d6c3d37f735596bf2b5e47517b495d641af
Sat Jan 22 03:14:26 UTC 2022

$ sleep 20

$ docker start -a b48a2a768679dd5cdb767d24f6632d6c3d37f735596bf2b5e47517b495d641af
Sat Jan 22 03:14:53 UTC 2022

$ docker ps -all
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED              STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
b48a2a768679   busybox   "date"    About a minute ago   Exited (0) 4 seconds ago             sad_robinson
```

Now I see two problems with the docker `ps -all` output:

1. I think I should list all my instances of docker start -- since the output was different, I reckon each was a different start of the same container (as you can see I only see one row in the `ps -all` output)
2. The output from `ps -all` seems to list the first start as I ran all of these commands right after the other and other than the sleep command all of them returned immediately yet the output of `ps -all` reflects a start time of "about a minute ago"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker ps` command lists containers, and the `docker start` command does not create new containers, so running it multiple times will not add additional entries to the `ps` output. Instead, what the `start` is doing is taking a non-running container and running it. The same would happen automatically with a restart policy on the container. The status in the `ps` output is the most recent status. Starting the container changes that status, as does stopping the container.

To create a new container that would be listed in `ps`, that's `docker container create`, or just `docker create`, which makes the container without starting it. Typically, people just use `docker run` which is a combination of `docker create` and `docker start` to create new containers.

Comment: Many thanks that really helped - so a non-running container can be restarted multiple times?